# Wordpress website got broken even Wordpress auto updates are disabled for both Wordpress core and plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, elementor

When i enabled debug mode i got this error.

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY t.name ASC' at line 1]
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('nav_menu') AND t.term_id NOT IN() ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Im using Elementor Pro for page building and website is working fine except Wordpress Menu got vanished automatically without updating any plugin or core wordpress update.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. There is a Wordpress plugin 'WPCoreSys' which gets added in the plugin folder automatically without showing anything in Wordpress  plugin section at Wordpress Dashboard. I went to cPanel and renamed that plugin which fixed this issue.